# configuring DynamicIpRestrictionModule on Azure web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, webforms, azure-web-app-service

We have an Asp.net web app running on the following stack : azure webapp, .Net 4.8, Telerik .Net AJAX components, Aspx webforms

in one of the pages we have a 403.502 error status when requesting page resources (Webresources.axd, css files, images etc ..)
using the browser dev tools we simulated a slow 3g network quality and the page loaded without any issue

we checked and we found that there is a module in webapp IIS called DynamicIpRestrictionModule that limits concurrent requests from the same client IP. When this limit is reached we have the 403.502 error (when we were on a slow 3g network, the concurrent limit is not reached, that's why the page load without any error)

Is there any way to increase or disable this limit ?

Thank you

Comment: Use a suitable tool to generate the XDT file, https://jenkins96.github.io/2023-04-08-Change-ApplicationHost.config-In-App-Service

Comment: `DynamicIpRestrictionModule` on Azure web app can be configured by Installing the Package from `SiteExtensions`.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AMtQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Lex Li for the comment.

I have found an extension for `Dynamic IP Restriction` in the `KUDU Console` => `Site extensions`.

`DynamicIpRestrictionModule` on Azure web app can be configured by Installing the Package from `SiteExtensions`.

- We can add the extension from the `Extensions` tab.

[image]

***OR***

- In the `Site extensions` => `Gallery` => search with `Dynamic` keyword.

[image]

[image]

- After installing the Extension, restart the WebApp to get the changes reflected.

[image]

- Click on `tab` to Launch the `Dynamic IP Restriction UI`.

[image]

***Dynamic IP Restriction UI:***

[image]

- Click on the `References`  link as shown below:

[image]

It will be redirected to the `techcommunity` blog.

Thanks @Vijay Saayi Ravinuthala for the clear steps.

As mentioned in the document, you can set the limit in `Web.config` file as well.

Also refer [SHAHRIAR HOSSAIN](https://learnwithshahriar.wordpress.com/2015/08/07/azure-website-101-azure-dynamic-ip-restriction/) document which explains the same configurations in `Web.config` file which is in `wwwroot` folder.

- I have updated the settings from UI, I can see the changes reflected in the newly created `applicationHost.xdt` file under `site` folder.

[image]

[image]